# Powershell : Retrive "Numa Node" Property from device manager

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to get  "Numa node" property that is displayed from "Details" of a device in device manager using powershell (Screenshot attached of device manager attached).

**The device class is "DiskDrive".**
Hoping the solution will work for any device class.

I tried using CimInstanceProperties but didn't find the property in it

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $phy_disk = Get-PhysicalDisk -DeviceNumber 0
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $phy_disk.CimInstanceProperties | findstr /i numa

PS C:\Users\Administrator> $get_disk_inst = Get-Disk -Number 0
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $get_disk_inst.CimInstanceProperties | findstr /i numa

PS C:\Users\Administrator> $pnp_device = Get-PnpDevice -Class DiskDrive -FriendlyName "ST2000DM008-2FR102"
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $pnp_device.CimInstanceProperties | findstr /i numa
PS C:\Users\Administrator>
```

[image]

Comment: "of a device" - _what kind of device_? What's the hardware class associated with this device?

Comment: I'm querying a device of class "DiskDrive". But I can see all devices have this entry.

Answer (score 2):

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-PnpDevice -Class diskdrive -FriendlyName "ST1000NM0008-2F2100" | Get-PnpDeviceProperty | where {$_.KeyName -like '*numa*'}

InstanceId KeyName                                   Type       Data
---------- -------                                   ----       ----
SCSI\DI... DEVPKEY_Device_Numa_Node                  UInt32     0
```

Comment: Would have been nice to see this properly formatted, and without the extra "data", in powershell.